# Refactoring using variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

I need to refactor 3-versions of a given function. Each has virtually identical code but parameters types differ.

```
template <typename... Args>
void myfunction(int value, varied_parameter_type param, Args... args) {
  ... do some work ...
}
```

Where `varied_parameter_type` is either:

- no-parameter at all (`void`),
- a `const char*`, or
- a `const my_class*`

For some reason, I'm drawing a blank on how to achieve this. My current thought is declare a *template<>* class to serve as a *parameter_type* and then specialize that accordingly, such as:

```
template <typename Type>
class parameter {
  public:
    Type value
  
    parameter(Type _val) : value(_val) { /* no-op */ }
    ~parameter(void) = default;
    
};
  
template<void> parameter;
template<const char*> parameter;
template<const my_class*> parameter;
```

Would someone please point me in the right direction? Web-site, white-paper, example code etc... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that a `const char*` and `const my_class*` is not allowed as the first argument in `Args... args`? Is `args` allowed to be empty?

Comment: Sometimes it's better  to actually create 2 separate functions with clear and descriptive names. One with `param` and one without - but it's hard to say without a real use-case.

Comment: It's difficult give a suggestion if we don't see how are different, your functions, regarding the use of `param`... anyway, if you can use C++17, what about using a `std::variant<std::monostate, char const *, my_class const *>`? `std::monostate` is used instead of `void`, that can't be used as a parameter type (or, maybe, you can use a `void *`). Anyway, your idea (a `parameter` template class) seems interesting, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to follow @Ted Lyngmo's initial suggestion of just passing the varied-parameters as the first parameter of Args... args. I don't really care for this approach but it is extraordinarily simple when compared to the other options that I was trying to use. I'd much rather that the varied_parameter be explicity defined as a part of the function call but alas, this will work.

And, as I said, it is a super-simple solution in comparison to my over-engineered thinking.